# Graphing Elliptic Cylinders

Tags: graphing-functions

Given a question to graph:

> x^2 + 4y^2 = 16

I would assume its a 2D Plot. My textbook assumes otherwise and treats it as a trace.

[image]

This is how the equation looks like when plotted.

> x^2 + 4y^2 = 16

[image]

My question is - is the 3D plot of x^2 + 4y^2 = 16 the same as the 2D plot of x^2 + 4y^2 = 16 except one is parallel to the plane and thats it? What distinguishes them? In the future if Im asked to draw a cylinder plane what would be the proper equation for it?

Comment: $z$ is arbitrary, so you just move up and down that ellipse along $z$ axis, and you get your elliptic cylinder.

Comment: So x^2 + y^2 = 1 is a cylinder?

Comment: I thought it would be x^2 + y^2 + z^1 = 1. But I forgot z is 0

Comment: what you wrote is sphere, not cylinder, and $z$ is not 0, its coefficient is zero.

Comment: x^2+y^2 = 1 is a restriction on the values of x and y. There is no restriction on z, so this equation represents a cylinder with axis along the z axis. Similarly, z = 0 is the horizontal plane in 3D as the only restriction on (x, y, z) is that z = 0. The equation y = 0 would represent the horizontal axis in 2D too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+4y^2 = 16$ is the same thing as saying that $x^2+4y^2+0z=16$. So $z$ will not affect your graph, but now you can graph this equation in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: It was worth the effort ;)